# extract the title from a cell array?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

how can I extract the title from a cell array?
 example :

```
for ii=1: nc
       figure( h(ii) )
            subplot( r,c,n(j) )

        bar(B,FF) %<== istogramma

        title('Istogramma Elemento',txt(1,2)); <==Istogramma Elemento : As
end



 I should write a routine in which they are created 4 figures. 
 within each figure are put 4 histograms. For each histogram changes the title.
```

the normal size of the matrix is of type 31x15

```
      1                2               3              4

'N° sul terreno'    'As ppm'    'Be ppm'    'Cd ppm'
'C26'              ''              ''               ''
'C23'            ''            ''               ''
'C19'            ''            ''               ''
'C11'            ''            ''               ''
'C27'            ''            ''               '' 
'C24'            ''            ''               ''
'C21'            ''            ''               ''
```

Comment: Is the matrix you showed us your cell array?  If that's the case, the first row of the cell array contains each title.  Remember, with cell arrays you need to use `{}` in order to access contents.  `()` is primarily used for slicing cell arrays (i.e. extracting cells within a specific range).  To access the first title, do `matrix{1,1}`, second title: `matrix{1,2}`, etc. etc. assuming `matrix` is your cell array.

Comment: @rayryeng is my matrix type text. but if I write : title('istogramma',txt{1,2}) or title('istogramma',txt(1,2)) have a error : h = title(gca,varargin{:}); but txt{1,2} = As ppm

Comment: What you are doing is specifying `title` with **two parameters**.  I'm assuming you just want to display **a single string**.  In that case, you need to do: `title(['istogramma ', txt{1,2}])`.  You need to ensure that the entire string is encompassed within `[]`.  You are specifying two parameters into the function when it only needs one.

Comment: @rayryeng ahhhhhhh superrrr. I have tried various combinations and I have not run that sugerita from you ...... I have problems with the FOR loop to make reading the row with the different elements

Comment: That's very easy.  Change your `title` line to this: `title(['Istogramma Elemento',txt(1,ii)]);`.  Your `for` loop goes from 1 up to `nc`.  Would `nc` be `4` in this case?

Comment: @rayryeng I did so, the routine reads me only the last element
my matrix is 31x15, but for conveniences use 4 just to try.
I could not answer that part of multiple figures.
you should see all the code.

Comment: @rayryeng for me, this is a first complex code with matlab. have basic problem. Thank you very much for your help and that of LuisMendo.

Comment: Not a problem.  Can you modify your post so that we can see your entire code?  This code seems to be incomplete and it doesn't describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This situation is frustrating. you be too strict with the scores. and do not understand how to retrieve the points to be able to write a post. I have included the full code and I have been taken 4 points.

Comment: I didn't downvote you.  I'm also sorry I haven't gotten back to your post.  I didn't have time to go through it because some of the loops you were doing didn't make any sense to me.  I can try to help you today if you are willing.

Comment: @rayryeng if I block the posts I can not write the whole cycle. if it were up to me, I will invierei code and matrix. I do not write well in English and I find it difficult to explain. And sorry for my english.

Comment: Put your code here: http://pastebin.com , copy and paste your code here, then send me a link to your code.

Comment: Ok. Now have little problem with internet connection. Sed u a code tomorrow in the mornig. Tnks friend

Comment: @rayryeng  [This is link for files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7UN9LtE-vzGMTg1MHJZLWJXTWs&usp=sharing) you can download the code with the arrays. 
I would like to make the sub plot with histograms 
enter the name of ppm As, Pb ppm ... etc histogram and overlap a standard normal curve (0.1). 
I am finding it difficult with the code. Tnks Friend

Comment: @rayryeng u see the link???

Comment: @rayreng sorry. U see the file code? Is a large code.

Comment: @rayryengI had problems with gmail. tomorrow or Saturday, I'll send the code sharing with gmail.

Comment: The code is large and sharing with gmail a zip with all file :)

Comment: @rayryeng this is the new link code :[link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7UN9LtE-vzGM2xHYXRzLVgtc2M&usp=sharing) sorry. you can place your code?

Comment: @rayryeng  I will have entered the code on gmail, because they are 200 lines. you can download the zip? I also added the data file.

Comment: @rayryeng the [link](http://pastebin.com/sMLSQPUD) code  but you don'have a matrix of data. The matrix for data code is in gmail.

Comment: I actually have no idea on what your code is doing when I took a first glimpse at it.  Instead of spending time on trying to fix it, I'm going to pass.  I hope someone else can help you fix your code.  Good luck.  Buona fortuna.